# how to show /hide answers under questions for FAQ page in android?

Tags: java, android

For my app i am creating FAQ page here i am using 2 layouts(one for questions and another one is for answers) and 1 activity I have 4 questions and answers  my layouts codings are

for questions

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qus1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How does ringee™ works?"
    android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qus2"
        android:text="Can I choose event places among the town/city localities?"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qus3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="When the reminder message will be sent to his/her invites?"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qus4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Is the reminder message customizable?"/>
```

For answers

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ans1"
        android:text="ringee™ provides platform to send reminder messages for your occasions , where in you can manage your occasion, your invites list and more features coming in near future. ringee™ is your one stop solution to manage your occasions and it can't be that easy before.
All you have to do is :-

    Create occasion types like Marriage, Party, Birthday, Anniversary Celebrations.
    Add invites list whom you want them invited.
    Select reminder days (On Event Day, 2 Days Before, Week Before) and activate."
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ans2"
        android:text="no ringee™ does'nt have this functionality, it will be soon available to the users"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ans3"
        android:text="ringee™ send reminder messages to invites at 10 AM Indian Standard Time[IST] on a day. This is routine task and will be send every day at 10 AM IST"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ans4"
        android:text="Users are given option to customize event text, but not event place and date and time of the event."
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

My activity code is

```
public class AboutActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

        TextView faq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faq);
        faq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.faq_activity);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

(above code just show the 4 questions in a page thats all)
  here i am showing 4 questions in a page when the user clicks a question  i have to show the corresponding answer under that question and that should be closed when they click some where else

any one can help me for that functionality?

Comment: What happens if the number of questions and answers keep increasing.. ? Do you keep adding new textviews?

Comment: no i didn't now i need functionality to view that questions and answers

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) instead of adding each item to your list

Answer (score 0):

Go this way

Take one vertical `LinearLayout` as root layout.

Inside LinearLayout take 8 `Textview`s. 4 for questions and 4 for answers.

The order of 8 textviews should be que1 , ans1 , que2 , ans2.....

Now set visibility of 4 answer textviews to `GONE`.

Now programatically on click event of any of 4 question textviews set their corresponding answer visibility to `VISIBLE` and put `onTouchListener` to parent LinearLayout and inside onTouchListener set answers textviews visibility to GONE

set answers textView visibility like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

To programatically change visibility use this

```
answer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: i created layout as you told but where and how to set visibility for 4 answers @bhargav

Comment: and do i want create 2 layouts?

Comment: no,you do not need 2 layouts. Only one is necessary

Comment: how to implement this concept you mentioned "programatically on click event of any of 4 question textviews set their corresponding answer visibility to visible." because here when the user clicks one the questions i have to visible that corresponding answer @bhargav

Comment: i did all as you told except ontouchlistener ,now i can view all answers when the questions clicked but i could not close that answer when move to another can u please give me functionality to hide the answer when move to another@bhargav

Comment: thank you so much i finished that page  as you told now it works @bhargav